# Where is the backup location from Titanium Backup on a phone without an SD card?

Tags: restore, titanium-backup

I am currently using a Samsung S6. Today I backed up all of my data with the app "Titanum Backup". After backing up all of the data, I transferred the folder of Titanium Backup to my Google Drive. Afterwards, I restored my phone. Then I installed Titanium Backup. However, I don't know where I need to import the folder "Titanium Backup" for the app to restore the the data. I saw many YouTube videos, and their restore was in a SD Card. However, the S6 doesn't have an SD card. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it on the internal SD card as well (e.g. `/sdcard/TitaniumBackup`). At its first start, *TiBu* will ask you to chose a location.

Comment: s6 don't have an  sd Card. So what should i do?

Comment: It hasn't even an *internal* SD card? So where does it store photos etc? Hard to believe ;)

Comment: @LouisRuan, try to understand: if your device doesn't have an external SD card, then the location /sdcard will point to internal SD card (it comes with all phones and S6 is no exception). Just make sure to download the folder from Drive and put it in the heart of `/sdcard/`. Use a file manager such as ES File Explorer. If TiBu doesn't detect the folder, go to its settings and choose the folder manually. Then reboot optionally.

Comment: For you it may be 'internal shared storage' or 'main storage' or similar name. Check with whatever file explorer app you have. And also you can always change the location of backups from within tb setting 'storage preferences'.